# Parameter validation for a method using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to perform parameter validation at compile time for an extension method.

Something like this

[image]

Here is the sample code of my program to validate

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sample = new Sample();
        var output = sample.SampleMethod("To Validate");  // I want to validate this param
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static string SampleMethod(this Sample sample, string sampleParam)
    {
        return sampleParam + " Hello";
    }
}

public class Sample
{

}
```

I am planning to use Roslyn but I don't know the `Action` to register and to get the parameter value that passed.

Sample code to validate parameter for a method using Roslyn will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://sharplab.io/ to look at the syntax tree of your code.

You might want to register an operation instead of an action:

```
context.RegisterOperationAction(YourAnalyzer, OperationKind.Invocation);
```

You can find lots of examples in these repos:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers
2. https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers
3. https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker